# JTextField only 13 or 17 digit valid and all invalid except (13 and 17)

Tags: java, swing

Currently I'm using this code but it's not working properly , when i remove 1 or 2 or 3 digit out of 17 but success icon still visible.

```
@Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            if(Strings.isNullOrEmpty(txtVID.getText())){
                lblIDValidation.setIcon(null);
                isVIDValid= false;
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                if(txtVID.getText().length()==16 || txtVID.getText().length()==12 || txtVID.getText().length()==17){
                    lblIDValidation.setIcon(createImageIcon(CommonUtil.success));
                    isVIDValid= true;
                    return;
                }
                lblIDValidation.setIcon(createImageIcon(CommonUtil.danger));
                isVIDValid= false;
        }
```

Comment: Like every other question on the subject, use a `DocumentFilter`, see [Implementing a Document Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) and [DocumentFilter Examples](http://www.jroller.com/dpmihai/entry/documentfilter) for more examples

Comment: Or a `DocumentListener` if you want to monitor the changes to a field, see  [Listening for Changes on a Document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#doclisteners) for more details. In any case, `KeyListener` is a poor choice (generally, but especially with text components)

Comment: The question and content are poorly described. See [mcve]

Comment: MadProgrammer. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `KeyListener` is a poor choice, generally, but espcially for text components, apart from not guaranteeing the order in which key events might be delivered to your listener, which could change the behavior on different platforms, they don't take into account what happens when you use `setText` or the user pastes text into the field.

A better choice is to use a `DocumentListener`, for example

```
    JTextField field = new JTextField(20);
    field.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {

        public void verify() {
            int length = field.getText().trim().length();
            if (length >= 16 && length <= 17) {
                field.setBackground(null);
            } else {
                field.setBackground(Color.RED);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            verify();
        }

        @Override
        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            verify();
        }

        @Override
        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            verify();
        }
    });
    field.setText(" ");
    field.setText(null);
```

See [Listening for Changes on a Document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#doclisteners) for more details

Comment: Thank you so much , It's work fine. I have used your advice and implemented in my code.
have a good life.

Answer (score 0):

Now it's working fine....If anyone have problem to use this code just comment below.

```
lblIDValidation.setIcon(null);
    txtVID.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
        public void verify() {
            int length = txtVID.getText().trim().length();
            if (length == 17 || length == 13) {
                lblIDValidation.setIcon(createImageIcon(CommonUtil.success));
                isVIDValid= true;
            } else {
                lblIDValidation.setIcon(createImageIcon(CommonUtil.danger));
                isVIDValid= false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            verify();
        }

        @Override
        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            verify();
        }

        @Override
        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            verify();
        }
    });
    txtVID.setText(null);
```

Comment: where CommonUtil.danger or success png images.